# Anchor Tags within IFrame - Not Triggering JQuery Function Call

Tags: jquery, iframe, anchor

I have a page on my site I use to display help topics from my products help system and it acts as a frame and includes an IFrame used to hold the content.  I use JQuery to populate the source of the IFrame when the page loads and also use JQuery to trigger a function that resizes the Iframe vertically.

The problem I have is that anchor tags within the called help topics do not of course call the JQuery function in the holding page because the content of the IFrame is simply re-populating itself on the basis of the anchor tag links.

Does anyone know how I can force the resize JQuery function using JQuery within the page holder and not in the called pages.

You can see this at www.meeting-manager.co.uk just click on the Concepts link at the bottom of the page and then click links in the See Also section.

Des Owen
www.meeting-manager.co.uk